# Read entire XML file and store in memory java

Tags: java

Here is what I am trying to do.

1. Read entire XML file (I do not care the name of element or attribute,etc..).
2. Save the read XML file into memory.
3. Update some values of read xml file.
4. Write back to a XML file.

I am trying to use XMLStreamReader to read a XML file, however all the examples I see so far, it looks like i have to provide element name.  But, I do not care about element names, just want to read entier XML file into memory.  And, I am not sure how datatype I should be storing as I am reading.  I am thinking to store them into Document datatype.

Any suggestions on how to read entire XML file and store read contents in memeory?

Thanks.

Comment: Without caring about the element name, attributes, etc., how can you expect your updates to end up in the right place?

Comment: Take a look at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html

Comment: Where do you want to add the content? end of file? if not, without knowing where to add, how can you locate the point?

Comment: So, i am planning on read entire file first, update specific element them write the entire contents back to another xml file.

Comment: You can use DOM, but JAXB is a lot easier because it binds the XML elements to POJO objects that can be manipulated with simple getters/setters. If you have an XML schema, you'll only have to write about 20 lines of code (for loading and saving) in addition to the code that actually modifies the data structures. Traversing and manipulating the DOM is a lot more tedious.

Comment: Thanks, rob.  I will take a look at this option as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be with [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html). You can use `xjc` to generate Java classes from your XML schema. Then use JAXB to unmarhsal (load) your data, manipulate the Java object just as you normally would any other object (using getters/setters), and marshal (save) it back to an XML file.

You could also use DOM directly, but manipulating the DOM is a lot more tedious than working with POJOs that directly mirror your XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLStreamReader` is an event-oriented parser that gives you a stream-like view of the XML. You apparently want the entire XML tree in memory, so the best option would be JDOM:

```
public Document parse(Reader in) {
  return new SAXBuilder().build(in);
}
```

The advantage of JDOM over JAXB is navigation: you can fetch an element deep into the XML tree with a simple expression like `"//my-elem"`. With JAXB you're going to write one barnful of code and nested loops to get this simple result.

(Not to mention that without the XML Schema of your XML, JAXB won't even talk to you.)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes JAXB could be overkill, and DOM is ok for a few manipulations:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = f.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("test.xml"));
```